# how to recognise handwriting and convert into text?

Tags: pattern-recognition

I'm trying to develop a project that recognises handwriting and converts into text. What are the algorithms and tools to be used?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the work of Alex Graves - https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/handwriting.html

Comment: This feels a bit much like a "do my homework for me"question to me.  Could you make this question a little more specific?

Comment: I need to know about handwriting recognition through image processing i.e recognising patterns of handwriting in the image. I need some suggestions. Whether it is feasible or not?

Answer (score 2):

What you described sounds to me like [Optical Character Recognition(OCR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

If you want to implement your own, I would say read through how an open source OCR like Tesseract was implemented.

Otherwise just google for OCR and you will find a list of OCR engines, both comercial and open-source. To list but a few:

- Tesseract: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
- Matlab Computer Vision Toolbox's OCR: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/vision/ref/ocr.html

Most OCRs makes use of a combination of a segmantation and image classification(usually done with Convolutional Neural Networks).

See [here](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/how-ocr-works.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) . But I want to recognise using image processing. How can I do that?